Why type might be nullable even don't explicity a nullable variable in Dart Class
I'm a beginer to Dart and I'm learning Factory Constructor. I wrote some code with VS code below:
class App {
  final String name;

  static final Map<String, App> _instance = <String, App>{};

  // short-form constructor
  const App(this.name);

  App._setVariable(this.name);

  // named constructor
  const App.anonymous(): this('no name');

  // factory constructor
  factory App.game(String name) {
    if (_instance.containsKey(name)) {
      return _instance[name];
    }else {
      final app = App._setVariable(name);
      _instance[name] = app;
      return app;
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'This is a $name App';
  }
}

Variable _instance is a map, which mapping a string to a App instance, I think the type in map _instance should be type of App, right? But VS code showed a type error that _instance[name] is a value of type App? in factory constructor.
Does it mean that _instance might be assigned a null value to it in run-time?
How this could be possible and how to fix this issue ?

I've learned that a nullable type can be declared as type? in Dart but I don't know the type error in VS code whether a programming feature of Dart or an IDE configuration issue.

The [] operator on maps returns null in case the key does not exist in the map. Since it is not really possible to be sure what is in the map at compile time, you need to move the null check to runtime (e.g. check if value from map are null): https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.3/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html

@julemand101 Thanks for your information. In my case, I firstly checked the key whether exists in the map with if (_instance.containsKey(name)), then fetch the value of that key. If the key doesn't exists in the map, then assign a value to it. Logically, there's no problem with this code. Any way, I learned that a value of an exist key in a map might be null according the link you provided. Even I declared the variable as a not nullable type, how could a value in a  not nullable variable be null?

The issue here is not that your map might contain a value of null for a certain key since your value-type are non-nullable. So in this scenario, it is more a matter of Dart not understanding that a check with "containsKey" means that a follow access would always return a value and not null because of missing value. It might look stupid but Map can be implemented by other classes and those classes might not have same guarantee.

The [] operator on maps returns null in case the key does not exist in the map. Since it is not really possible to be sure what is in the map at compile time, you need to move the null check to runtime (e.g. check if value from map are null). Yes, even if checking first with containsKey since there are no guarantee that every Map implementation would make sure containsKey returns true if the key are in the Map when requesting with [] (yes, sounds silly but since nothing prevents this... it is possible).
There are multiple solutions to make your code more clean here. I think using putIfAbsent would be the most fitting:
  // factory constructor
  factory App.game(String name) =>
      _instance.putIfAbsent(name, () => App._setVariable(name));

The putIfAbsent method are made to return the value for a given key if it exists in the map and if not, it will put the generated value into the map and then return this new instance.

Or use a pattern: if (_instance[name] case var name?) return name;. Or with ??=: => _instance[name] ??= App._setVariable(name);.
